# I'm struggling with very slow Axios requests in asyncData

Tags: vue.js, axios, server-side, nuxt.js

nuxt: 2.4.5
@nuxtjs/axios: 5.4.1

I fetch data in asyncData and it lasts like 5s, it makes loading a page awfully long, it is related to axios request, when I do the same, but in method `created` instead of asyncData, everything is perfect.

I've tried to reinstall all dependencies and use older versions and the newest as well with the same result.

```
    asyncData({ app: {$axios} }) {
      // this is very slow
      return $axios.get('/api/v1/advertisements').then(() => {});
    },
```

```
    created() {
      // this works perfect
      this.$axios.get('/api/v1/advertisements').then(() => {});
    },
```

Axios requests should works the same when using in created and asyncData.

Answer (score 2):

They are working same. It means your api return data for 5 seconds, so u need to see what wrong with your api.

The difference between asyncData and created is that in asyncData nuxt will wait for request to be completed before rendering page, and in created it wont wait and just will render page and update it later with request result

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are calling your API to your local endpoint when you call it from the `asyncData` hook. It makes a HUGE difference if you call your request to your local server.

You can set up an endpoint for your server request, and client one such as:

```
if(process.browser){
 $axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com'
}else{
 $axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://127.0.0.1:8000'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently: requests sent from the server-side were slow while on the client it was ok. In order to understand the difference between them, it is useful to investigate the request configs.

In axios, every response contains the request config. Log it like this:

```js
const res = await $axios.request({
    URL,
    method: 'GET',
});
console.log(res.config);
```

Then open the page that performs this request and collect the logs for both server- and client-side. In my case, the server was sending redundant cookies and Authorization header which were handled in the wrong way on the back-end.

Therefore, the problem might be as in your front-end code as in the back-end. Hope it helped to investigate your own problem.